# How to disable default response for springdoc openapi and swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have a problem with a springdoc-openapi and swagger. In api.yml file I defined some responses for endpoint, for example:

```
responses:
  200:
     desription: example response
     content:
     ......
  404:
     description: example response
```

And before that the behavior was expected to me. In swagger I saw an example value for 200 and I didn't see an example value for 404, only description. When I started to use springdoc-openapi, when I didn't provided content for example for 404, the content from 200 is applied to 404.
Is there a option how to hide it? For example in api.yml or any config property?

I tried to search config properties but I din't find anything. Moreover I tried with content: {} but It didn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

> It is be possible to handle as return an empty content as response using, one of the following syntaxes:
>
> - `content = @Content`
> - `content = @Content(schema = @Schema(hidden = true))`

For example:

```java
  @GetMapping
  @ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "example response"),
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "example response", content = @Content)
  })
  public String index() {
    return "Hello";
  }
```

For RestControllerAdvice

```java
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
  @ExceptionHandler({ RuntimeException.class })
  @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "example response", content = @Content)
  @ResponseBody
  public String handleError() {
    return "NotFound";
  }
```

Please see: https://springdoc.org/#how-can-i-return-an-empty-content-as-response

Answer (score 0):

To remove the default 'mediaType' and 'example value,' you should do the following:

```
@Operation(
    description = "Example",
    summary = "Example",
    method = "Example",
    responses = [
        ApiResponse(
            responseCode = "204",
            description = "No Content",
            content = [Content(mediaType = "")]
        )
    ]
)
```

When you open your Swagger UI again, the default response should be gone.